# get unique Tasks From relation

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-5, foreach

I have relation tags that have many tasks whet I get data from foreach I get duplicated values

in example

in my path i have 2 tags PHP ,HTML5

PHP Has [PHP Task_1 , PHP_Task_2]

HTML5 Has [HTml5 Task_1,PHPTask_2]

because task has many tags so i will get to duplicated PHP_Task_2

i need to get every task just one time

My Controller

```
    $posts2 = Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
     {$q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {$q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)
            ->with('tasktags');
        }]);
    }])->where('id', '=', 1)->get();
```

My Blade

```
@foreach ($posts2 as $item)
      <h2> {{$item->name}}</h2>
   @foreach ($item->pathtags as $Tag)

   <li> Path Tag :: {{ $Tag->name }} </li>

   @foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task)
    <li> Task :: {{ $Task->task_name }} </li>

   @foreach ($Task->tasktags as $TaskTag)
    <li> Task Tags :: {{ $TaskTag->name }} </li>

@endforeach
 @endforeach 
 @endforeach
 @endforeach
```