# Add elements to an array inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop, foreach

'm trying to get non duplicated in My blade  tasks using  this Code

I have Edited My Question So i added Controller and full blade Code

My Controller

```
    $posts2 = Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
     {$q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {$q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)
            ->with('tasktags');
        }]);
    }])->where('id', '=', 1)->get();
```

My Blade

```
     @foreach ($posts2 as $item)
      <h2> {{$item->name}}</h2>
  @foreach ($item->pathtags as $Tag)
@foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task)

   @php $a=array(); @endphp

    @if (in_array($Task->task_name,$a))
    <li> Task :: {{ $Task->task_name }} </li>
@php
    array_push($a,"$Task->task_name");
 @endphp
@else {
<li> Task :: Not Found </li>
}
@endif
@endforeach
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: is $tag a collection ?

Comment: No  it's array of relation

Comment: Can't you use stock PHP array_count_values?

Comment: No i cant  please check My other ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020431/get-unique-tasks-from-relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are emptying the array in each iteration. move the initialization of array before the foreach loop. also, the whole logic is wrong. you are checking if the item exists in the array, and if so, add it again.

```
@php $a=array(); @endphp
@foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task)
    @if (!in_array($Task->task_name,$a))
        <li> Task :: {{ $Task->task_name }} </li>
        @php
            array_push($a,$Task->task_name);
        @endphp
    @else 
          <li> Task :: Duplicated </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Still i get empty array

Comment: OK No errors this time but it  return  duplicated Tasks although it returns if not else so i think we have missed something

Comment: i do not understand. what is your desired output that you are not getting with this? if you just wanna show unique tasks, you can completely delete the @else section

Comment: the array is cleaned after getting tasks from tag

Comment: I have and i added full blade Code

Comment: I'm still confused about what you want in your output, but maybe you should put the $a initialization even higher and before all foreach loops if you do not want any repetitive task name AT ALL

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
array_push($a,"$Task->task_name");
```

with

```
array_push($a, $Task->task_name);
// or
$a[] = $Task->task_name;
```

Comment: Not Working id did dd($a) and i get empty array

Answer (score 0):

In stock PHP you can use array_count_values to get the count of each array items.

Then use array_diff or array_intersect to get the different unique or duplicated items.
Array_keys return the values from original array.

```
$arr = ["one", "one", "two", "two", "three"];

$count = array_count_values($arr);

echo "duplicates \n";
var_dump(array_keys(array_diff($count, [1])));

echo "uniques \n";
var_dump(array_keys(array_intersect($count, [1])));
```

https://3v4l.org/DKIbZ